# Find object in list with given property value then find dictionary value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a list of objects. Each of these objects has a `Name` property, and an `ObservablePairCollection` which is just a custom dictionary that works EXACTLY like a dictionary, has a key/value pair.

Given two strings, one for name and one for key, I want to find the object that first matches the name given, and then selects the `pair` from that model's dictionary that matches the given key value.

Example: Given the string "model1" for name, and "Latitude" for the key, an object who's name property equals `model1` should be found, and then a key/value pair in the object's dictionary should be returned where the key equals `Latitude`.

Currently I can do the first part to match the `Name` by using:

```
private ObservableCollection<ModelBase> models;
//add objects to models

string stringToFind = "model1";

models.Single(m => m.Name == stringToFind);
```

So, this returns the object who's `Name` property equals `model1`.

I'm unable to find the right statement to use to get the key/value pair though.

Here's the relative parts of the class:

```
private ObservablePairCollection<string, string> _fields = new ObservablePairCollection<string, string>();
public ObservablePairCollection<string, string> Fields
{
    get { return _fields; }
    set { _fields = value; OnPropertyChanged("Fields"); }
}

private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    protected set
    {
        if (_name != value)
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to use LINQ if possible, but not a huge deal if not.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need something like this: `models.Single(m => m.Name == "someName").Fields.Single(f => f.Key == "Latitude");`

Comment: @Nino why would you ever use `Single` when searching a key in a dictionary?

Comment: @InBetween, you're right, `First()` is better approach.

Comment: Thank you @Nino, InBetween's is a cheaper way of doing it, but yours did work for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why `Single`? Must there be only one object with the given `Name` and must you *enforce* it in this specific code? Bear in mind that `Single` is expensive because it will enumerate the whole collection to make sure the found object is unique.

If you are just interested in finding the first, if any, then simply use the aptly named `First` extension method:

```
models.First(m => m.Name == stringToFind);
```

Ok, so that returns the first object with a given `Name`, if any, you simply need to filter the `Fields` proyerty:

```
var pair = models.First(m => m.Name == stringToFind)
                ?.Fields
                 .First(f => f.Key = keyToFind);
```

Comment: Well, there will always be 6 instances of these objects, each one has a unique name. So once I find the one w/ the right name, I don't have to use single to find the key/value pair.

Comment: @pfinferno `First` is the cheapest returning the seeked pair, it will stop iterating once it finds the first match. `Where` or `Single` will iterate the whole enumeration, which is more expensive.